# CSS: Center text in button

Tags: css

I would like to center the text in a button, however, it seems to sit too far down, at least in Chrome. Any tricks? I've tried setting line-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCKYp/

```
<button>go</button>

button{ 
  background:yellow;
  height:23px; 
  width:28px; 
  padding:0;
   margin:0;
  border:solid black 1px; 
    line-height:23px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using line-height, you need to set it equal to the font-size.

Also add `vertical-align: top`

```
button {
    background:yellow;
    height:23px;
    width:28px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:solid black 1px;
    line-height:13px;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BCKYp/8/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Thought it had to be equal to the height, silly me.

Comment: `vertical-align: top` does not change anything

Comment: @ExplosionPills It does change something, like positioning the button to the top instead or the bottom. Explained here with example: http://jsfiddle.net/BCKYp/20/

Answer (score 2):

Setting line-height equal to element's height is working properly if your text written in uppercase. Line-height is expected to be used as a property for styling paragraphs and using it for centering element in a div or a button you'll have to adjust it's value for every specific case.

In your case you can either adjust the line-height visually or use padding-top and padding-bottom for sizing the element.

Comment: This. For added control you might want to set `box-sizing: border box;` as it removes the crossbrowser border+padding sizing isues.

Answer (score 1):

I used `padding-bottom` and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCKYp/22/

Answer (score 1):

This is a case by case question, personally I would remove the `height` and `line-height` and set `top` and `bottom` `padding`. It also looks slightly skewed due to the nature of the character 'g' taking up more space below.

My preference would be:

```
button{ 
  background:yellow; 
  width:28px; 
  padding:5px 0;
  margin:0;
  border:solid black 1px; 
}
```

Here's an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GupPM/)**, you can adjust the padding to suit your needs. I've also added another button to show with more centred characters. Y.

Comment: I would do this as well. Line heights between broswers differ and ive found that using this method produces the best cross browser results in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set a smaller `line-height`, but really I would use a reset css file to make sure this will have similar effects on all browsers.

```
 line-height: 21px;
```

As the above will look different on the other browsers but will fix the problem for Chrome. Its an ugly solution in otherwords.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more property in your **css** class. Add following property to your class

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

don't give width and height,

http://jsfiddle.net/BCKYp/12/

```
button{ 
  background:yellow;
  padding:2px;
  margin:0;
  border:solid black 1px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear centered because `g` and `o` only extend halfway up the baseline.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/BCKYp/1/

However, you can *reduce* the `line-height` (to `11px` for example) to give the illusion of moving the lower-cased letters upwards:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/BCKYp/4/